# Facing difficulty in geometric optic: What is the scientific use of the real images formed by lens and how they not affect our vision? Like in specs

Tags: geometric-optics, lenses

I have myopia but still why don't I see diminished images. I tried many YouTube videos wherein I have found how real images in mirror are of no practical use but yet they are visible ....with lens I couldn't see any real image in the first place so knowing it's practical use is a different thing all together.

Comment: Hi, to get useful responses, please be a bit more detailed.  Can you define "diminished image" for us?  The standard terms are "real" and "virtual" image planes.   It may be that you have simply forgotten that the output of spectacles is then refocussed by the lens inside your eye.

Comment: There's probably a definite answer to your question, unfortunately I don't really understand what you are asking about. Feel free to edit your question, it's free. Things that are unclear: What do you mean by "diminished" image? What exactly do those videos say about real images in mirrors and in what sense are they not useful? In what sense do you think you can't see real images with lens?